# Python Selenium - print text in child elements

Tags: python, selenium

I want to print all the text within the child elements of this div id "dataWarnings"

My code -

```
def check_warnings():
    driver.find_element(By.ID,'Warnings-tab').click()
    container1 = driver.find_elements(By.ID,'dataWarnings')
    
    for items in container1:
        mytext = items.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id="JobStatusOkWithWarnings"]")
        print (mytext.text)
```

My modules -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from time import sleep
```

HTML -
[image]

Desired output -

```
1 Jobs Process successfully for Product Code WIP04499
No Activity Messages
No General Errors
Jobs that have been created
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Number: WIP04499-601
1 Job Activity Messages
Failed to generate task [Reason :There were no mapped By-Products found for stage [Company :Freshcut Foods] [Process :Prepped By Hand] [Version :1] [Stage :Material Output (By-Product)]]
No Job Errors
4 Job Tasks
4374 - Batch Finish Time
4375 - Batch Start Time
4376 - Output Quantity And Batch Number
4377 - Input Quantity And Batch Number
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Current Output -

```
(literally blank)
```

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). You may like to consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71033719/print-all-text-within-child-elements-selenium-python @undetectedSelenium