# Print all text within child elements - Selenium - Python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to print all the text within the child elements of this div id "dataWarnings". Typing until
I can post the question. Seems like I have to keep typing more text. Holy moly now even more text is being typed.

My code -

```
def check_warnings():
    driver.find_element(By.ID,'Warnings-tab').click()
    container1 = driver.find_elements(By.ID,'dataWarnings')
    
    for items in container1:
        mytext = items.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id="JobStatusOkWithWarnings"]")
        print (mytext.text)
```

My modules -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from time import sleep
```

HTML -

```
<div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="dataWarnings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
    <div id="JobStatusOkWithWarnings">
        <b><u>1 Jobs Process successfully for Product Code WIP04499</u></b><br />
        <br />
        <b>No Activity Messages</b><br />
        <br />
        <b>No General Errors</b><br />
        <br />
        Jobs that have been created<br />
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br />
        <b>Job Number: WIP04499-622</b><br />
        <br />
        <b>1 Job Activity Messages</b><br />
        <br />
        Failed to generate task [Reason :There were no mapped By-Products found for stage [Company :Freshcut Foods] [Process :Prepped By Hand] [Version :1] [Stage :Material Output (By-Product)]] <br />
        <br />
        <b>No Job Errors</b><br />
        <br />
        <b>4 Job Tasks</b><br />
        <br />
        4458 - Batch Finish Time<br />
        4459 - Batch Start Time<br />
        4460 - Output Quantity And Batch Number<br />
        4461 - Input Quantity And Batch Number<br />
        <br />
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br />
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Desired output -

```
1 Jobs Process successfully for Product Code WIP04499
No Activity Messages
No General Errors
Jobs that have been created
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Job Number: WIP04499-601
1 Job Activity Messages
Failed to generate task [Reason :There were no mapped By-Products found for stage [Company :Freshcut Foods] [Process :Prepped By Hand] [Version :1] [Stage :Material Output (By-Product)]]
No Job Errors
4 Job Tasks
4374 - Batch Finish Time
4375 - Batch Start Time
4376 - Output Quantity And Batch Number
4377 - Input Quantity And Batch Number
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Current Output -

```
(literally blank)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't believe this took me so long to realize, I used

```
    parent = WebDriverWait(driver,delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'dataWarnings')))
    text = parent.get_attribute('innerText')
    print (text)
```